# Vim shows multiple errors before starting

Tags: vim

SOLVED: bad colorscheme .vim file.

Whenever I start up vim, I always get a flood of errors and then a "Press ENTER or type command to continue" message. Then vim works fine.

I just have no idea what the cause of it is.I am on a Linux machine.

```
line 5045:
E488: Trailing characters:     </div>
line 5048:
E488: Trailing characters:       <script crossorigin=
line 5049:
E488: Trailing characters:       <script async=
line 5052:
E488: Trailing characters:         <script async src=
line 5053:
E488: Trailing characters:   </body>
line 5054:
E488: Trailing characters: </html>
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

Here is my .vimrc file. It is just the example one with some editing. I am still a beginner.

```
" An example for a vimrc file.
"
" Maintainer:   Bram Moolenaar <Bram@vim.org>
" Last change:  2011 Apr 15
"
" To use it, copy it to
"     for Unix and OS/2:  ~/.vimrc
"         for Amiga:  s:.vimrc
"  for MS-DOS and Win32:  $VIM\_vimrc
"       for OpenVMS:  sys$login:.vimrc

" When started as "evim", evim.vim will already have done these settings.
if v:progname =~? "evim"
  finish
endif
syntax enable
colorscheme solarized
" Use Vim settings, rather than Vi settings (much better!).
" This must be first, because it changes other options as a side effect.
set nocompatible

" allow backspacing over everything in insert mode
set backspace=indent,eol,start

if has("vms")
  set nobackup      " do not keep a backup file, use versions instead
else
  set backup        " keep a backup file
endif
set history=50      " keep 50 lines of command line history
set ruler       " show the cursor position all the time
set showcmd     " display incomplete commands
set incsearch       " do incremental searching

" For Win32 GUI: remove 't' flag from 'guioptions': no tearoff menu entries
" let &guioptions = substitute(&guioptions, "t", "", "g")

" Don't use Ex mode, use Q for formatting
map Q gq

" CTRL-U in insert mode deletes a lot.  Use CTRL-G u to first break undo,
" so that you can undo CTRL-U after inserting a line break.
inoremap <C-U> <C-G>u<C-U>

" In many terminal emulators the mouse works just fine, thus enable it.
if has('mouse')
  set mouse=a
endif

" Switch syntax highlighting on, when the terminal has colors
" Also switch on highlighting the last used search pattern.
if &t_Co > 2 || has("gui_running")
  syntax on
  set hlsearch
endif


execute pathogen#infect()

set nopaste


" Only do this part when compiled with support for autocommands.
if has("autocmd")

  " Enable file type detection.
  " Use the default filetype settings, so that mail gets 'tw' set to 72,
  " 'cindent' is on in C files, etc.
  " Also load indent files, to automatically do language-dependent indenting.
  filetype plugin indent on

  " Put these in an autocmd group, so that we can delete them easily.
  augroup vimrcEx
  au!

  " For all text files set 'textwidth' to 78 characters.
  autocmd FileType text setlocal textwidth=78

  " When editing a file, always jump to the last known cursor position.
  " Don't do it when the position is invalid or when inside an event handler
  " (happens when dropping a file on gvim).
  " Also don't do it when the mark is in the first line, that is the default
  " position when opening a file.
  autocmd BufReadPost *
    \ if line("'\"") > 1 && line("'\"") <= line("$") |
    \   exe "normal! g`\"" |
    \ endif

  augroup END

else

  set autoindent        " always set autoindenting on

endif " has("autocmd")

" Convenient command to see the difference between the current buffer and the
" file it was loaded from, thus the changes you made.
" Only define it when not defined already.
if !exists(":DiffOrig")
  command DiffOrig vert new | set bt=nofile | r ++edit # | 0d_ | diffthis
          \ | wincmd p | diffthis
endif

set number
```

Comment: Are you using Linux machine?

Comment: Yes, I am using Linux.

Comment: try setting `:set fileformat=unix`

Comment: Thank you for your help! But I have solved it. It was a bad colorscheme .vim file.

Answer (score 3):

Vim complains about HTML tags, so it looks like you've installed a bad Vimscript, grabbing a (formatted) web page instead of the raw contents.

Either go back to the page and copy/paste from the browser, or (e.g. in GitHub) get the **raw** file contents and save that.